# tm_map and stopwords failed to remove unwanted words from the corpus created in R

Tags: r, tm, stop-words, tidytext

I have a resulting data frame which has the following data:

```
                   word freq
credit           credit  790
account         account  451
xxxxxxxx       xxxxxxxx  430
report           report  405
information information  368
reporting     reporting  345
consumer       consumer  331
accounts       accounts  300
debt               debt  170
company         company  152
xxxxxx         xxxxxx    147
```

I want to do the following:

- remove all the wods which has more than two x such as xx, xxx, xxx
  and so forth, since these words can be in lower or upper case so have to
  bring into lower case first then remove

I am using tm_map for removing the stopwords but it seems, it didn't work and I still got the unwanted words in the dataframe as above.

```
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(df$txt))
myStopwords <- c(stopwords('english'),"xxx", "xxxx", "xxxxx", 
                 "XXX", "XXXX", "XXXXX", "xxxx", "xxx", "xx", "xxxxxxxx",
                 "xxxxxxxx", "XXXXXX", "xxxxxx", "XXXXXXX", "xxxxxxx", "XXXXXXXX", "xxxxxxxx")
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, tolower)
myCorpus<- tm_map(myCorpus,removePunctuation)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords, myStopwords)

myTdm <- as.matrix(TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus))
v <- sort(rowSums(myTdm), decreasing=TRUE)
FreqMat <- data.frame(word = names(v), freq=v, row.names = F)
head(FreqMat, 10)
```

This code above didn't work for me for removing unwanted words from corpus.

is there any other alternative to deal with this issue?

Comment: Looks like some whitespace. Especially the last line in your example. tm has a `stripWhitespace` function. `tm_map(myCorpus, stripWhitespace)` should take care of it. Run this line of code just before removing the stopwords.

Comment: @phiver - thanks for suggestions, in my code I have modified it now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility involving `dplyr` and `stringr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(word = tolower(word)) %>%
 filter(str_count(word, fixed("x")) <= 1)

         word freq
1      credit  790
2     account  451
3      report  405
4 information  368
5   reporting  345
6    consumer  331
7    accounts  300
8        debt  170
9     company  152
```

Or a `base R` possibility using a similar logic:

```
df[sapply(df[, 1], 
          function(x) length(grepRaw("x", tolower(x), all = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)) <= 1, 
          USE.NAMES = FALSE), ]
```

Comment: less than or greater than 1 ?? in your solution, you wrote `filter(str_count(word, "x") <= 1)` which means, as I guess, character counts of x in the string <= (less than or equal to). is it the case? otherwise, it would be really helpful if you could include some explanation to the work. Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: It simply converts the words to lowercase, then computes the number of `x` and filters out those words which contain more than 2 of them.